# About PDF Viewing and Editing PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I have two type of users in my php website. According to my client specs , One  user can edit PDF's at browser and another user can read them. He want it something like we see in gmail inbox.

Can anybody please suggest how can I achieve this in PHP.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? What has a PDF todo with Gmail inbox? I don't know what your question is and what you want todo.

Comment: My question is can I implement google docs viewing and editing in php website ? Like when we recieve a pdf in inbox and click on the view then it opens it in the google docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load your documents into Google docs (and use their ability to edit files) then refer to their [Google Docs API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/documents/docs/developers_guide.html).

This way you can use their tools without spending time writing your own.

Comment: Thanks for Replying, Can you please suggest me another php way to achieve this. Writer can upload files(pdf,docs) from his login,can edit after logging in and Reader can Only read after login.

Comment: I don't know if there's already a script todo so. You probably have to script your own then.